# how can I plot the span of a matrix 3x2 in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I tried this way:

```
    gl1 =
   -2.5000   -1.0000
    4.3301    1.7321
    0         0
syms a b
span=gl1(:,1)*a+gl1(:,2)*b
a=[-100:0.1:100];
b=[-100:0.1:100];
span=eval(span)
```

and then I'd do plot3(span).
unfortunatly at the last row it gives me this error:

```
Error using vertcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.

Error in sym/eval (line 11)
s = evalin('caller',vectorize(map2mat(char(x))));
```

any idea? I've found someone using a polytope method to do it,but I have no idea where I can get or I how can I realize such method.

thanks you in advice.

edit:in this case the span should be a line,since the rank of my matrix is one,but the question stands for a matrix with rank 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use symbolics? This works like a charm:

```
gl1 =
   -2.5000   -1.0000
    4.3301    1.7321
    0         0

a=[-100:0.1:100];
b=[-100:0.1:100];

span=gl1(:,1)*a+gl1(:,2)*b
```

Remember that you need several inputs to [`plot3`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/plot3.html), i.e. the x, y, and z-values. Thus it should be something like this:

```
plot3(span(1,:),span(2,:),span(3,:))
```

Comment: that's beautyfull! I always use symbolics just beacouse I started a week a go,and I still don't get the difference between a variable and a sym. anyways the problem in my code was the row of zeros. for some reason (it was beacouse a and b do not appear in the last row of gl1) I din't get a row of zeros but just the two declared in gl1. inizialising the variable before I use them is way better than my symbolics obsession. thanks a lot

Comment: sorry to bother you again,but if I plot the span of a plane (say x=[1 0 0]' t=[1 1 0]' with plot3 in the exact same way I only get a line. should I use mesh to plot planes?

Comment: @user3149593: Yes =) Both [`mesh`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/mesh.html) and [`surf`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) (short for surface) could be used for planes. `plot3` is for plotting lines in a 3D-space.